# How to group assets by category/sub-category

Tags: categories, group

I have a section called “products” that has an asset field called “product-docs”. The assets are pdf files that have a Category field. Each product can have many different types of documents; to make it easier to find the document you want (on a product page), there are five different Document Categories, each of which has a number of Document Types, e.g.:

Installation Guides (Document Category)
Mounting instructions (Document Type)
Wiring Instructions (Document Type)

What I want to do is to show all documents for a given product, grouped by Document Category. If I fetch the data for the document category field it returns a string that comprises both the Document Category and the Document Sub Category. Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish: https://www.ruskin.com/model/aiq-td-50 (docs are grouped by category in the section labelled Additional Resources)

How can I query the category field so that I can access the Document Category and then all the related Sub Categories? I tried using .level1, but that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m assuming you want to do this in Twig rather than PHP, since you haven’t specified nor have you provided any code.

First, fetch all assets, eager-loading the categories.

```
{% set assets = entry.product-docs
    .with('category-field-handle')
    .all()
%}
```

Then use the [`group`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/filters.html#group) filter to group the assets by the category title.

```
{% set assetGroups = assets|group(asset => asset.category-field-handle.one().title) %}
```

Finally, output the assets, grouped by category title:

```
{% for categoryTitle, assetGroup in assetGroups %}
    {{ categoryTitle }}

    {% for asset in assetGroup %}
        {{ asset.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: A thousand thanks, Ben - worked perfectly! Only minor change was to use asset.category-field-handle[0] instead of .one().

Comment: `.one()` should work fine in Craft 4.

Comment: Good to know - in the process of moving the site from Craft 3 to Craft 4. Thanks again, Ben - much appreciated!